# Pulling data from separate book based on cell A1's value

Tags: vba

I have two workbooks and I am trying to pull data from `Book2` into `Book1` based on the cell value that I put into `A1` of `Sheet1` of `Book1` . There are 40 different sheets in `Book2`, but all data is the in the same format, so cell positioning is the same.

So what I want to be able to do is type in `"sheet6"` into `A1` and have the relevant data be pulled from `Book2`. Ideally, I would want to have this cell referenced into my code.

If you could show the code with a basic example of two books and a couple of sheets with embedding of cell `A1` that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

To have code run based on changing a cell's value, use the `Worksheet_Change()` event. Test to see if it's `A1` that was changed. If so, use its value as the sheet name within `Book2`.

Here's an example that does that and returns the value from `A1` on the specified sheet of `Book2` and puts it in `A2` on your active sheet in `Book1`:

```
' In Book1, Sheet1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Was A1 changed?
    If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then

        ' Yes. Get the sheet name that was entered...
        Dim strSheet As String
        strSheet = Target.Text

        ' Using that sheet name, return a value from Book2...
        Range("A2") = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Sheets(strSheet).Range("A1")

    End If

End Sub
```